# Handling file open using javascript

Tags: javascript

I am calling a function OpenFileHotlink(),it is working fine for first time but when i am not selecting any file for open,it is opening previous file, how can i handle it if there is no selected file then it should not open.

I have tried to clear call stack using timeout function.

```
<fieldset>
 <legend>File Name</legend>
<!----Here i am getting all files as dropdown and it changing on the basis of objectId(This is another dropdown option) and file types----->
<select id="hotlinkfilenames_Id" class="form-control">
<!-- <option value="">------Select------</option> -->
</select>
</fieldset>
<div class="col-md-12 text-center pt-10">
                                        <a  class="btn btn-success btn-xs" id="geturlOpenFileHotlink"  onclick="OpenFileHotlink()">Open</a>
</div>
```

```js
function OpenFileHotlink() {
  var fileName = $("#hotlinkfilenames_Id").val();
  var id=[];
  var uri='';
  alert(fileName);

  if(fileName==null||fileName=='' ){
    alert("Please select File Name");
    //debugger;
    return false;
  }else{
    alert("");
    fileName=fileName.toString();
    id =fileName.split("/");

    var ext1=id[1].toString();
    var ext=ext1.split(".");

    var htmlOpenHotlink="";
    $.ajax({
      url:'./openFile1/'+id[0],
      async: false, 
      cache: false,
      type:'POST',
      //dataType:'json',
      success:function(response){
        uri='data:image/'+ext[1]+';base64,'+response+'';
        document.getElementById("geturlOpenFileHotlink").href = uri;
        document.getElementById("geturlOpenFileHotlink").download = id[1];
      } 
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: add your html file also

Comment: what does it mean `no selected file then it should not open.`? Open in the sense it shows the name of uploaded file.

Comment: no selected file then it should not open means After changing id there is no files are available, But when i am clicking on open button it is opening previous selected file

Comment: why are you mixing normal javascript and jquery e.g getElementById?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have got solution of my question:
I added this line in my if condition, means if filename==null then 
document.getElementById("geturlOpenFileHotlink").href='#';

Answer (score 0):

If all you want to do is clear the input field then simply setting the value attribute (or `val()` in jQuery) to an empty string will work.

In your success callback in the ajax request, add this at the end

```
$("#hotlinkfilenames_Id").val("");
```

---

**Edit based on the updates in question**

I'd give you the plain (vanilla) js approach for this. (It's absolutely okay to use js alongside jquery. Jquery is just a library which extends plain js).

```
document.getElementById('hotlinkfilenames_Id').innerHTML = '';
```

Add this to your success method and it'll clear the select dropdown.
Hope it helps.

Comment: Oh.. Okay. I was under the impression that the `#hotlinkfilenames_Id` is an `input[type='file']` but now that I'm seeing the html, I see that it is a select element. You'd need to provide a little more context of where the file is coming from. In the meantime if you want to clear the previous options in the select dropdown you could just clear the inner html of the element. I'll update my answer.

Comment: Actuallly i'm getting files in dropdown on the basis of selecting objectId and file type, so whenever i am changing objectId,it is reloading files dropdown .

Comment: so when i am clicking on open button without selecting any file it is opening previous selected file while i am using if condition, if filename is null then it return false upto this condition my code is correct(control of function is coming out but it is calling callstack function internally and it is opening previous selected file) .I have checked it using debugger. So, i want solution to handle call stack function because it is containing previous called function with older data.